# Relacionar grupos entre os Pesquisadores com pelo menos 2 áreas em comum no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso agrupar todos os usuário do tipo Pesquisador (idUsuarioTipo = 3) que possuam 2 áreas em comum (idAreaAtuacao)

Exemplo: Maria, Pedro, José e Roberto possuem as áreas Meio ambiente e Ecologia em comum.

Exemplo2: João, Maurício e Fernando possuem as áreas Energias Renováveis e Meio Ambiente em comum.

Exemplo3: Elisa e Leonora possuem as áreas Programação e Mecânica dos Fluidos em comum.

Algumas tentativas que eu fiz:

```
SELECT d.idAreaAtuacao, a.*
FROM (((usuarios_cadastro as a
INNER JOIN relacao_area_usuario as b ON b.idUsuarioCadastro=a.idUsuarioCadastro)
INNER JOIN relacao_atuacao_grande_area as c ON c.idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea=b.idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea)
INNER JOIN (SELECT idAreaAtuacao, COUNT(*)
FROM relacao_atuacao_grande_area 
GROUP BY idAreaAtuacao
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2) as d ON  c.idAreaAtuacao=d.idAreaAtuacao);
```

Como mostrado acima tentei primeiro fazer a contagem de repetição das áreas, porém não consigo visualizar como posso filtrar os usuários para separá-los pela áreas em comum. A partir disso tentei o seguinte:

```
SELECT e.idUsuarioCadastro FROM relacao_area_usuario AS e
INNER JOIN relacao_atuacao_grande_area AS f ON e.idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea = f.idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea
WHERE f.idAreaAtuacao = 15 AND (((SELECT group_concat(a.idUsuarioCadastro) FROM relacao_area_usuario AS a
INNER JOIN relacao_atuacao_grande_area AS b ON a.idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea = b.idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea
WHERE idAreaAtuacao = 12) = (SELECT group_concat(c.idUsuarioCadastro) FROM relacao_area_usuario AS c
INNER JOIN relacao_atuacao_grande_area AS d ON c.idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea = d.idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea
WHERE idAreaAtuacao = 39)) IS NOT NULL)
```

A ideia foi fazer comparações entre dois grupos de idUsuarioCadastro e a parte de idAreaAtuacao seriam comparadas em uma estrutura de while (sendo que essa estrutura precisaria comparar cada valor de id com todos os outros id e assim por diante) que eu não consegui fazer.

Por favor me ajudem, estou a semanas tentando resolver e não consigo :/

SEGUE O BANCO

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;


-- Copiando estrutura do banco de dados para dig_busqueaqui
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `dig_busqueaqui` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
USE `dig_busqueaqui`;

-- Copiando estrutura para tabela dig_busqueaqui.areas_atuacao
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `areas_atuacao` (
  `idAreaAtuacao` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nomeAreaAtuacao` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `descricao` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `idAreaGrande` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAreaAtuacao`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idAreaAtuacao_UNIQUE` (`idAreaAtuacao`),
  KEY `idAreaGrandeAreaAtuacao_idx` (`idAreaGrande`),
  CONSTRAINT `idAreaGrande` FOREIGN KEY (`idAreaGrande`) REFERENCES `areas_grandes` (`idAreaGrande`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Copiando dados para a tabela dig_busqueaqui.areas_atuacao: ~23 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `areas_atuacao` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `areas_atuacao` (`idAreaAtuacao`, `nomeAreaAtuacao`, `descricao`, `idAreaGrande`) VALUES
    (1, 'Instrumentação Eletrônica', NULL, 1),
    (2, 'Circuitos Eletrônicos', NULL, 1),
    (3, 'Materiais e Componentes Semicondutores', NULL, 1),
    (4, 'Interdisciplinar', NULL, 1),
    (5, 'Redes Neuronais Artificiais', NULL, 10),
    (6, 'Gestão Ambiental', NULL, 6),
    (7, 'Inteligência Artificial', NULL, 10),
    (8, 'Dispositivos Optoeletrônicos', NULL, 1),
    (9, 'Química dos Alimentos', NULL, 8),
    (11, 'Desenvolvimento de Produto', NULL, 9),
    (15, 'Tecnologia de Bebidas', NULL, 5),
    (17, 'Física dos Alimentos', NULL, 5),
    (18, 'Físico-Química dos Alimentos', NULL, 5),
    (19, 'Bioquímica dos Alimentos', NULL, 5),
    (20, 'Bioquímica das Mat-primas Alimentares', NULL, 5),
    (21, 'Inovação Tecnológica', NULL, 5),
    (23, 'Engenharia de Software', NULL, 12),
    (24, 'Gestão de Projetos', NULL, 12),
    (25, 'Banco de Dados', NULL, 12),
    (26, 'Educação a Distância (EaD)', NULL, 12),
    (34, 'Metodologias Ágeis de Desenvolvimento de Software', NULL, 12),
    (38, 'Garantia de Controle de Qualidade', NULL, 6),
    (39, 'Fontes Renováveis de Energia', NULL, 7);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `areas_atuacao` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Copiando estrutura para tabela dig_busqueaqui.areas_grandes
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `areas_grandes` (
  `idAreaGrande` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nomeAreaGrande` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `descricao` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAreaGrande`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idGrandeArea_UNIQUE` (`idAreaGrande`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Copiando dados para a tabela dig_busqueaqui.areas_grandes: ~12 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `areas_grandes` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `areas_grandes` (`idAreaGrande`, `nomeAreaGrande`, `descricao`) VALUES
    (1, 'Engenharia Elétrica', NULL),
    (2, 'Engenharia de Alimentos', NULL),
    (3, 'Engenharia Química', NULL),
    (4, 'Engenharia Civil', NULL),
    (5, 'Ciência e Tecnologia de Alimentos', NULL),
    (6, 'Engenharia de Produção', NULL),
    (7, 'Engenharia de Energia', NULL),
    (8, 'Engenharia Química', NULL),
    (9, 'Engenharia de Produto', NULL),
    (10, 'Engenharia da Computação', NULL),
    (11, 'Agronomia', NULL),
    (12, 'Ciência da Computação', NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `areas_grandes` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Copiando estrutura para tabela dig_busqueaqui.cadastro_gargalos
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cadastro_gargalos` (
  `idCadastroGargalo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idUsuarioCadastro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dataCadastro` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `gargalo` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dispostoInvestir` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCadastroGargalo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idGargaloCadastro_UNIQUE` (`idCadastroGargalo`),
  KEY `idUsuarioCadastroGargalo_idx` (`idUsuarioCadastro`),
  CONSTRAINT `idUsuarioCadastroGargalo` FOREIGN KEY (`idUsuarioCadastro`) REFERENCES `usuarios_cadastro` (`idUsuarioCadastro`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Copiando dados para a tabela dig_busqueaqui.cadastro_gargalos: ~3 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cadastro_gargalos` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `cadastro_gargalos` (`idCadastroGargalo`, `idUsuarioCadastro`, `dataCadastro`, `gargalo`, `dispostoInvestir`) VALUES
    (1, 1, '2020-09-03 00:45:47', 'Problema na medicao do tempo de pega do gesso', b'1'),
    (2, 6, '2020-09-05 11:44:42', 'Leitura de Tags RFID', b'0'),
    (3, 7, '2020-09-05 12:24:40', 'Problema em criar um novo produto', b'0');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cadastro_gargalos` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Copiando estrutura para tabela dig_busqueaqui.cadastro_palavras_chave
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cadastro_palavras_chave` (
  `idCadastroPalavraChave` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dataCadastro` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `palavraChave` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCadastroPalavraChave`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idPalavraChave_UNIQUE` (`idCadastroPalavraChave`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Copiando dados para a tabela dig_busqueaqui.cadastro_palavras_chave: ~10 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cadastro_palavras_chave` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `cadastro_palavras_chave` (`idCadastroPalavraChave`, `dataCadastro`, `palavraChave`) VALUES
    (5, '2020-09-05 12:07:29', 'RFID'),
    (6, '2020-09-05 12:07:29', 'Rastreabilidade'),
    (7, '2020-09-05 12:07:29', 'Tempo de Pega'),
    (8, '2020-09-05 12:07:29', 'Gesso'),
    (9, '2020-09-05 12:07:29', 'Medição Automática'),
    (10, '2020-09-05 12:07:29', 'Controle de Qualidade'),
    (11, '2020-09-05 12:07:29', 'Sementes'),
    (12, '2020-09-05 12:33:25', 'Notícias'),
    (13, '2020-09-05 12:33:25', 'Dashboard'),
    (14, '2020-09-05 12:33:25', 'Clippings');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cadastro_palavras_chave` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Copiando estrutura para tabela dig_busqueaqui.cadastro_tipos
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cadastro_tipos` (
  `idCadastroTipo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idUsuarioTipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `descricao` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCadastroTipo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idTipoCadastro_UNIQUE` (`idCadastroTipo`),
  KEY `idUsuarioTipo_idx` (`idUsuarioTipo`),
  CONSTRAINT `idUsuarioTipoCadTip` FOREIGN KEY (`idUsuarioTipo`) REFERENCES `usuario_tipos` (`idUsuarioTipo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Copiando dados para a tabela dig_busqueaqui.cadastro_tipos: ~4 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cadastro_tipos` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `cadastro_tipos` (`idCadastroTipo`, `idUsuarioTipo`, `nome`, `descricao`) VALUES
    (1, 3, 'Empresa', 'Nome da empresa que representa'),
    (2, 3, 'Microempreendedor Individual (MEI)', NULL),
    (3, 4, 'ICT', 'Nome da institução que representa'),
    (4, 4, 'Pesquisador Independente', NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cadastro_tipos` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Copiando estrutura para tabela dig_busqueaqui.relacao_area_gargalo
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relacao_area_gargalo` (
  `idRelacaoAreaGargalo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idAreaAtuacao` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idCadastroGargalo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dataCadastro` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`idRelacaoAreaGargalo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idRelacaoAreaGargalo_UNIQUE` (`idRelacaoAreaGargalo`),
  KEY `idAreaAtuacaoRelAreGar_idx` (`idAreaAtuacao`),
  KEY `idCadastroGargaloRelAreGar_idx` (`idCadastroGargalo`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- Copiando dados para a tabela dig_busqueaqui.relacao_area_gargalo: 15 rows
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `relacao_area_gargalo` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `relacao_area_gargalo` (`idRelacaoAreaGargalo`, `idAreaAtuacao`, `idCadastroGargalo`, `dataCadastro`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, '2020-09-03 00:56:36'),
    (2, 8, 1, '2020-09-03 00:56:36'),
    (3, 1, 2, '2020-09-05 11:47:21'),
    (4, 21, 2, '2020-09-05 11:47:21'),
    (5, 38, 2, '2020-09-05 11:47:21'),
    (8, 11, 2, '2020-09-05 12:01:55'),
    (9, 25, 2, '2020-09-05 12:01:55'),
    (10, 21, 1, '2020-09-05 12:19:02'),
    (11, 25, 1, '2020-09-05 12:19:02'),
    (12, 3, 1, '2020-09-05 12:19:45'),
    (14, 5, 1, '2020-09-05 12:19:45'),
    (15, 23, 3, '2020-09-05 12:36:58'),
    (16, 25, 3, '2020-09-05 12:36:58'),
    (17, 11, 3, '2020-09-05 12:36:58'),
    (18, 24, 3, '2020-09-05 12:36:58');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `relacao_area_gargalo` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Copiando estrutura para tabela dig_busqueaqui.relacao_area_usuario
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relacao_area_usuario` (
  `idRelacaoAreaUsuario` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idUsuarioCadastro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dataCadastro` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `relacaoAtiva` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idRelacaoAreaUsuario`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idRelacaoAreaUsuario_UNIQUE` (`idRelacaoAreaUsuario`),
  KEY `idUsuarioCadastroRelAreUsu_idx` (`idUsuarioCadastro`),
  KEY `idAreaAtuacaoRelAreUsu_idx` (`idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea`),
  CONSTRAINT `idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeAreaRelAreUsu` FOREIGN KEY (`idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea`) REFERENCES `relacao_atuacao_grande_area` (`idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea`),
  CONSTRAINT `idUsuarioCadastroRelAreUsu` FOREIGN KEY (`idUsuarioCadastro`) REFERENCES `usuarios_cadastro` (`idUsuarioCadastro`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Copiando dados para a tabela dig_busqueaqui.relacao_area_usuario: ~28 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `relacao_area_usuario` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `relacao_area_usuario` (`idRelacaoAreaUsuario`, `idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea`, `idUsuarioCadastro`, `dataCadastro`, `relacaoAtiva`) VALUES
    (11, 17, 2, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (12, 4, 5, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (13, 19, 5, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (14, 6, 2, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (15, 21, 3, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (16, 23, 3, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (17, 18, 3, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (18, 9, 3, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (19, 13, 3, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (20, 12, 3, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (21, 5, 3, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (22, 22, 4, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (23, 24, 4, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (24, 10, 4, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (25, 11, 4, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (26, 3, 4, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (27, 2, 4, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (28, 16, 5, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (29, 8, 5, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (30, 14, 5, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (31, 1, 5, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (32, 7, 5, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (33, 20, 5, '2020-09-03 17:22:27', 1),
    (34, 15, 4, '2020-09-04 19:27:56', 1),
    (35, 50, 3, '2020-09-04 19:33:15', 1),
    (36, 51, 4, '2020-09-04 19:36:37', 1),
    (40, 58, 3, '2021-01-14 12:39:34', 1),
    (41, 5, 6, '2021-01-14 15:10:23', 1),
    (42, 58, 6, '2021-01-14 15:12:18', 1),
    (43, 55, 6, '2021-01-18 16:13:38', 1);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `relacao_area_usuario` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Copiando estrutura para tabela dig_busqueaqui.relacao_atuacao_grande_area
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relacao_atuacao_grande_area` (
  `idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idAreaAtuacao` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idAreaGrande` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea_UNIQUE` (`idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea`),
  KEY `idAreaAtuacaoRelAtuGraAre_idx` (`idAreaAtuacao`),
  KEY `idAreaGrandeRelAtuGraAre_idx` (`idAreaGrande`),
  CONSTRAINT `idAreaAtuacaoRelAtuGraAre` FOREIGN KEY (`idAreaAtuacao`) REFERENCES `areas_atuacao` (`idAreaAtuacao`),
  CONSTRAINT `idAreaGrandeRelAtuGraAre` FOREIGN KEY (`idAreaGrande`) REFERENCES `areas_grandes` (`idAreaGrande`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Copiando dados para a tabela dig_busqueaqui.relacao_atuacao_grande_area: ~27 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `relacao_atuacao_grande_area` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `relacao_atuacao_grande_area` (`idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea`, `idAreaAtuacao`, `idAreaGrande`) VALUES
    (1, 25, 12),
    (2, 20, 5),
    (3, 19, 5),
    (4, 2, 1),
    (5, 11, 9),
    (6, 8, 1),
    (7, 26, 12),
    (8, 23, 12),
    (9, 39, 7),
    (10, 17, 5),
    (11, 18, 5),
    (12, 38, 6),
    (13, 6, 6),
    (14, 24, 12),
    (15, 21, 5),
    (16, 21, 12),
    (17, 1, 1),
    (18, 7, 10),
    (19, 4, 1),
    (20, 34, 12),
    (21, 9, 8),
    (22, 9, 5),
    (23, 5, 10),
    (24, 15, 5),
    (50, 4, 8),
    (51, 4, 5),
    (55, 39, 11),
    (58, 21, 11);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `relacao_atuacao_grande_area` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Copiando estrutura para tabela dig_busqueaqui.relacao_palavras_gargalos
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relacao_palavras_gargalos` (
  `idRelacaoPalavraGargalo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idCadastroPalavraChave` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idCadastroGargalo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idRelacaoPalavraGargalo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idRelacaoPalavraGargalo_UNIQUE` (`idRelacaoPalavraGargalo`),
  KEY `idCadastroPalavraChaveRelPalGar_idx` (`idCadastroPalavraChave`),
  KEY `idCadastroGargaloRelPalGar_idx` (`idCadastroGargalo`),
  CONSTRAINT `idCadastroGargaloRelPalGar` FOREIGN KEY (`idCadastroGargalo`) REFERENCES `cadastro_gargalos` (`idCadastroGargalo`),
  CONSTRAINT `idCadastroPalavraChaveRelPalGar` FOREIGN KEY (`idCadastroPalavraChave`) REFERENCES `cadastro_palavras_chave` (`idCadastroPalavraChave`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Copiando dados para a tabela dig_busqueaqui.relacao_palavras_gargalos: ~13 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `relacao_palavras_gargalos` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `relacao_palavras_gargalos` (`idRelacaoPalavraGargalo`, `idCadastroPalavraChave`, `idCadastroGargalo`) VALUES
    (9, 5, 2),
    (10, 6, 2),
    (11, 7, 1),
    (12, 8, 1),
    (13, 9, 1),
    (14, 10, 1),
    (15, 11, 2),
    (16, 10, 2),
    (17, 12, 3),
    (18, 13, 3),
    (19, 14, 3),
    (20, 6, 1),
    (21, 5, 1);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `relacao_palavras_gargalos` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Copiando estrutura para tabela dig_busqueaqui.usuarios_cadastro
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios_cadastro` (
  `idUsuarioCadastro` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `idUsuarioTipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idCadastroTipo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataCadastro` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `nomeEntidade` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipoVinculo` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUsuarioCadastro`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idCadastroUsuario_UNIQUE` (`idUsuarioCadastro`),
  KEY `idCadastroTipoCadastro_idx` (`idCadastroTipo`),
  KEY `idUsuarioTipoCadastro_idx` (`idUsuarioTipo`),
  CONSTRAINT `idCadastroTipoCadastro` FOREIGN KEY (`idCadastroTipo`) REFERENCES `cadastro_tipos` (`idCadastroTipo`),
  CONSTRAINT `idUsuarioTipoCadastro` FOREIGN KEY (`idUsuarioTipo`) REFERENCES `usuario_tipos` (`idUsuarioTipo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Copiando dados para a tabela dig_busqueaqui.usuarios_cadastro: ~7 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `usuarios_cadastro` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `usuarios_cadastro` (`idUsuarioCadastro`, `nome`, `idUsuarioTipo`, `idCadastroTipo`, `telefone`, `email`, `dataCadastro`, `nomeEntidade`, `tipoVinculo`) VALUES
    (1, 'Igo Silva', 3, 1, '074991413673', 'contato@webgotech.com.br', '2020-09-03 00:44:19', 'WebGO Technologies', 'Diretor'),
    (2, 'Isnaldo Coelho', 4, 3, '07421027630', 'isnaldo.coelho@univasf.edu.br', '2020-09-03 00:44:19', 'UNIVASF', 'Professor Assistente II'),
    (3, 'Vivianni Marques', 4, 3, '07436141937', 'vivianni.santos@gmail.com', '2020-09-03 11:46:31', 'UNIVASF', 'Professora Assistente II'),
    (4, 'Marcos Lima', 4, 3, '08721014300', 'marcos.santos@ifsertao-pe.edu.br', '2020-09-03 17:08:30', 'IF Sertão PE', 'Professor efetivo'),
    (5, 'Mário Godoy', 4, 3, '07421027636', 'mariogodoyneto@gmail.com', '2020-09-03 17:08:30', 'UNIVASF', 'Professor Assistente II'),
    (6, 'Tiago Silva', 3, 2, '074988585787', 'tiagosilva@outlook.com', '2020-09-05 11:26:47', NULL, NULL),
    (7, 'Diego Alves', 3, 2, '074988141516', 'diego.alves@gmail.com', '2020-09-05 12:22:26', NULL, NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `usuarios_cadastro` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Copiando estrutura para tabela dig_busqueaqui.usuario_tipos
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuario_tipos` (
  `idUsuarioTipo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `descricao` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUsuarioTipo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idtipoUsuario_UNIQUE` (`idUsuarioTipo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Copiando dados para a tabela dig_busqueaqui.usuario_tipos: ~4 rows (aproximadamente)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `usuario_tipos` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `usuario_tipos` (`idUsuarioTipo`, `nome`, `descricao`) VALUES
    (1, 'Administrador', NULL),
    (2, 'Visitante', NULL),
    (3, 'Empresário', NULL),
    (4, 'Pesquisador', NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `usuario_tipos` ENABLE KEYS */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

Comment: e o que já tentou? pode colocar a query na pergunta?

Comment: Vou adicionar o que tentei, porém sempre chego em soluções pela metade, sou novo aqui

Comment: No lugar da imagem do diagrama é melhor postar a definição de suas tabelas. Veja [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas)

Comment: qual versão do MySQL você está utilizando?

Comment: @imex A versão do MySql é a 8.0

Comment: @anonimo você fala o código das tabelas?

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu adicionei a Query

Comment: precisa explicar melhor o que seria *"Preciso agrupar todos os usuário do tipo Pesquisador (idUsuarioTipo = 3) que possuam 2 áreas em comum (idAreaAtuacao)"* Consegue colocar um exemplo do resultado esperado na pergunta? Peguei o seu código e coloquei n db-fiddle para ajudar aqui: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vkxX3U7ct7rYbgPUBGwdnL/0  Veja que fiz umas queries, filtrando os agrupado por repetição para ter uma ideia dos dados

Comment: @imex Muito Obrigado!!!

Comment: @RicardoPontual muito obrigado pela atenção e tentativas, Imex conseguiu me mostrar como faz, muito obrigado por me mostrar esse site de teste, não conhecia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não cheguei a testar, pode ser que tenha alguns erros, mas segue uma sugestão para testes:

```
with CTE_UsuarioAreas as
(
    select
        ra1.idAreaAtuacao as idAreaAtuacao1,
        ra2.idAreaAtuacao as idAreaAtuacao2,
        u.idUsuarioCadastro,
        count(*) over(partition by ra1.idAreaAtuacao, ra2.idAreaAtuacao) as QtdeUsuarios
    from usuarios_cadastro as u

    inner join relacao_area_usuario as ru1 
        on u.idUsuarioCadastro = ru1.idUsuarioCadastro
    inner join relacao_atuacao_grande_area as ra1 
        on ru1.idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea = ra1.idRelacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea

    inner join relacao_area_usuario as ru2 
        on u.idUsuarioCadastro = ru2.idUsuarioCadastro
    inner join relacao_atuacao_grande_area as ra2 
        on ru2.idRElacaoAtuacaoGrandeArea = ra2.idRelacaoAtuaaoGrandeArea

    where
        u.idUsuarioTipo = 3 and
        ra1.idAreaAtuacao < ra2.idAreaAtuacao
)

select 
    idAreaAtuacao1,
    idAreaAtuacao2,
    idUsuarioCadastro
from CTE_UsuarioAreas
where
    QtdeUsuarios > 1
order by
    idAreaAtuacao1,
    idAreaAtuacao2
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!!!!!!! muito obrigado mesmo!! é exatamente isso.